# Excel Countif on all previous rows is stalling

Tags: excel, range, absolute, countif

I need to count matching cells on all previous rows preceding the cell with formula. I am currently using following method combining relative and absolute range:

```
B2: =COUNTIFS($A$1:A1;"condition")
.
.
.
BN: =COUNTIFS($A$1:AN;"condition")
```

This method, however, proves to be extremely rigid for numbers of rows 10-20k+.

It often freezes excel not only when copying rows but surprisingly for me also when deleting them. Is there any more neat solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than evaluating the condition (n*(n+1))/2 times, you could take advantage of the fact that you've already done most of the work in the previous cell.

B1: `=0+condition`
B2: `=B1+condition`
B3: `=B2+condition`

Note that this relies on `condition` evaluating to 1 when `TRUE` and 0 when `FALSE` if used in an arithmetic expression. You could rewrite it as `IF(condition, 1, 0)` if you prefer.

Comment: sorry, my bad, the countif is located in different column than data. I have corrected the question.